# UNIQUE INDEX not working

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a unique index with where the condition. but it is not working. maybe I am missing something.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_NBR_TIN_INFO_PASSPORT] 
ON [dbo].[NBR_TIN_INFO] ([PASSPORT_NUMBER] ASC)
WHERE (([PASSPORT_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL) AND ([IS_TOKEN_APPROVED] <> 0))
GO
```

Data inserted in the table is shown here:

```
PASSPORT_NUMBER | IS_TOKEN_APPROVED
----------------+-------------------
XXX-487545      | NULL
XXX-487545      |   0
XXX-487545      | NULL
```

But row 1 or 3 should be blocked by index.

Comment: when I using WHERE ([PASSPORT_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL OR [IS_TOKEN_APPROVED]<>0) is shows the error message ""Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'."

Comment: You need to skip the filter, see my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because NULL is unknown in every comparison, i.e. neither 0 = NULL nor 0 <> NULL. Therefore, you don't get these rows indexed. Try this:

```
WHERE (([PASSPORT_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL)
  AND ([IS_TOKEN_APPROVED]<>0 OR [IS_TOKEN_APPROVED] IS NULL))
```

Comment: The result of comparison to `NULL` is not false, but unknown. You can't compare something to nothing.

Comment: ERROR.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @TT. thanks for correction.

I don't see a 'with' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve this by adding both columns to your index and removing the filter

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_NBR_TIN_INFO_PASSPORT] 
    ON [dbo].[NBR_TIN_INFO] ([PASSPORT_NUMBER] ASC), 
       [dbo].[NBR_TIN_INFO] ([IS_TOKEN_APPROVED])
GO
```